# Electron app gets slower when there are thousands of records in indexeddb

Tags: electron, indexeddb, pouchdb

I have always wondered if indexeddb was ever built to support thousands of records (100K), because I have developed a desktop app using electron that uses pouchdb and has almost 100k records in it, and the desktop app becomes slower often. The desktop app also syncs the data to and fro to a remote couchdb.

To verify whether this is because of the number of data records, I deleted many records and the app was performing better than before.

My question is, isn't indexeddb capable of handling so many data?

Comment: Give [leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb) a try.  PouchDB has an adapter for it.

Comment: Also, what leads you to believe it's the backing store that is the root of the performance issue - are you able to isolate with a unit test that demonstrates this behavior?